# WCF Error 400 Bad Request when POST some data

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a WCF Service  in my local machine that works like a "bridge" between a client application and a database in remote.

The WCF service works with Entity Framework classes and works fine when get the data but doesn't work when post anything and i getting the next error message: "(400) Bad Request".

This is my client code:

```
//Connect to WCF Service
CHS_Local.ServiceFrontalClient proxy = new CHS_Local.ServiceFrontalClient();

//Get a "Client" class wich ClientID == 1
CHS_Local.Client client = proxy.GetClient(1);

//Change some stuff
client.Name = "change someting";

//Send the modified class to service to update the database
proxy.UpdateClient(client);
```

This my `<system.serviceModel>` tag in wcf config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <services>
      <service name="CentralizedHostingService.ServiceFrontal">
         <endpoint 
             address="" 
             binding="wsHttpBinding" 
             contract="CentralizedHostingService.IServiceFrontal">
            <identity>
               <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
         </endpoint>
         <endpoint 
             address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
         <host>
            <baseAddresses>
               <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/CentralizedHostingService/Service1/" />
            </baseAddresses>
         </host>
     </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
       <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
       </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And my `app.config` in client application:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IServiceFrontal" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" 
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas 
                   maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" 
                   maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                   maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                               proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                             negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                             algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint 
            address="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/CentralizedHostingService/Service1/"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IServiceFrontal"
            contract="CHS_Local.IServiceFrontal" name="WSHttpBinding_IServiceFrontal">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Service Interface:

```
    [OperationContract]
    Client GetClient(int clientID);

    [OperationContract]
    void UpdateClient(Client editedClient);
```

In a first instance I though that the problem resides in the weight of the petition but i see using Fiddler that bytes send for the petition are only 115.903 bytes (~0.11MB).
Any idea?

As you can see is a simple example but don't works :(

Thanks for you help! :)

Comment: Put your service interace here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set `maxReceivedMessageSize` and `readerQuotas` (if needed) on the service when posting data from client. Your client configuration has modified `maxReceivedMessageSize` which works for getting data from service but when you send large amount of data to the service you must modify its configuration as well.

Something like:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="myBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="500000" />
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="CentralizedHostingService.ServiceFrontal">
      <endpoint bindingConfiguration="myBinding" ... />
      ...
    </service>
  </services>
  ...
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I already updated config in client and server. But the error remaining.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced this issue in my staging environment when i will send more bytes over the wire.

```
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

below changes i made it in WCF web.config file(include lessthen and greaterthen symbol in the below configuration since i could not add due to invisible of the tag)

From:

```
 binding name="ServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="**262144**"
```

To

```
 binding name="ServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="**2147483647**"
```

Below is the end point address tag for above binding

```
 endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="**ServiceBinding**"
```

After above changes then it works like charm.

Thanks,
M.Amalraj